# How to charge lithium ion batteries - BMS (and) TP4056

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have this [BMS module](https://www.banggood.com/3S-20A-Li-ion-Lithium-Battery-18650-Charger-PCB-BMS-Protection-Board-12_6V-Cell-p-1118043.html?rmmds=detail-top-buytogether-auto&cur_warehouse=CN) for 3 cell lithium ion battery protection. as [this guy explain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYnxmXvkMYE) the BMS modules can charge the batteries but not ideally, so we need a separate charger module to fully charge the batteries.

[TP4056](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-5V-1A-Micro-USB-18650-Lithium-Battery-TP4056-DW01A-Charger-Board-Module-/191850083395) is what i'm gonna use as a charger module.

TP4056 is a one cell module and provides 4.2V output, while each cell connected to different parts of BMS module which requires different voltages from batteries in order to monitor over-charge/discharge.

Does TP4056 module conflict with the BMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't charge each cell of multicell battery with TP4056 ICs.

See this:

[TP4056 modules with 18650 lithium cells](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274020/tp4056-modules-with-18650-lithium-cells)

and this:

[series charging three 18650 batteries with three chargers off the same 5V supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/348128/series-charging-three-18650-batteries-with-three-chargers-off-the-same-5v-supply)

for example.

Also you can't combine this BMS with TP4056 (what the reason?). By the way, no charger can charge cell "ideally".

Comment: so it's either BMS OR the charger? but BMS can't charge the batteries(fully)! what's the solution for that?

Comment: @newbie TP4056 can handle one cell battery only. You don't need BMS for this at all. You can't charge multicell battery by many TP4056 ICs from the same source at the same time. You need special 3S LiPo charger, which can charge every cell of 3S battery at the same time AND balance them. There is rather complex task, typically based on MCU or rather complex analog schematics.